# How can I find the names of all shares on a LAN without knowing any machine names using C#?

Tags: c#, networking, share

How can I find all the shares on a LAN without knowing any machine names or domain names using C#? I've found all kinds of solutions if you know the machine name but that isn't going to be available to me. I'm looking to obtain something similar to whats below:

> //joescomp/public
>   //beth/apps
>   //server/pdf
>   //server/public

So it will show the name of the machine and whats shared on it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that in fairly simple way.

- Get you current [IP Address and Subnet network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219762/list-ip-all-addresses-in-a-subnet)
- Scan the whole subnet, [check each IP for shares it has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567063/get-a-list-of-all-unc-shared-folders-on-a-local-network-server). If you need you can [convert IP to machine name](http://www.dijksterhuis.org/converting-an-ip-address-to-a-hostname-and-back-with-c/) but you can just work with ip's as well (for purpose of showing you can do reverse dns checking on those IP's)
- That's it :-)